# how to display new message when system reaches the given time?

Tags: android

hi all how to adjust code for displaying the time and date as like system time and date.
and how to display the new toast message if system time is 12:30:20pm date 27-08-2011   my given time is 04:40:09 pm My date 28-08-2011 in between this time i fixed 120 minute when system reaches the 120 minute i have to display one toast like  "u have new message". so help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a handler that waits for a message. To this handler you could send a delayed (120 minutes) message:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed%28android.os.Message,%20long%29